# find elements that are identical jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a collection of `th` elements and in the click handler on the `th` element I want to find the item in the list that is the same as `e.target` in the click handler.

```
var $ths = $('table th');

$ths.on('click', function(e){
   var $th = $(e.target);
   //how to get the index of $th in $trs
});
```

I want to know if which `th` I clicked on (first, second, third, etc).

(i do not have control over the markup as this is a third party library loaded on the page).

Comment: what do you mean by identical... what determines it

Comment: to get index you can use `var index = $(this).index();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index()` returns index of element.

Try:

```
$ths.on('click', function(e){
   var $th = $(this).index();
   alert($th);
});
```